# Bootstrapping Proportions of Categorical Variables in R or Stata

Tags: r, stata, statistics-bootstrap

I need help in doing bootstrap in either R or Stata software. I want to calculate the proportion of those who say Yes and No to e.g. effectiveness of a policy

In Stata I have this code

```
bs "summarize y1" "r(mean)", reps(200) size(770)
```

what should be the value for `r(mean)` to estimate the proportions?

Also, I have this code in R:

```
test <- function (q13){
    test13 <- table(q13)
    rel_freq <- test13/sum(test13)
    return(rel_freq)
      }

results <- boot(data=q13, statistic=test,
                R=200)
```

How do I correct the code? I'm getting the error

> Error in statistic(data, original, ...) : unused argument(s) (original)

Comment: For R, read the examples in `?boot` carefully - your function `test` needs to take at least two arguments, the second of which should be a set of indices that will be used to resample the underlying data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Stata** you can use `proportion` if a variable has more than two categories:

//sample data

```
sysuse auto, clear
keep if (headroom==2.0 |headroom==2.5)
gen prop=.
replace prop=0 if headroom==2.0
replace prop=1 if headroom==2.5
```

//say 0 is yes and 1 is no

```
set seed 123
bootstrap _b, reps(100):proportion prop
```

**Updated as per @Nick**: For binary variable, the following is sufficient

```
bootstrap r(mean), reps(100): summarize prop, meanonly
```

..........................................................................................................................................................................

In **R**, you can do as follows using `boot` package and mtcars data:

```
library(boot)
set.seed(123)
x<-mtcars$vs
myprop<-function(x,i){
sum(x[i]==0)/length(x)
}

bootprop <- boot(x,myprop,100)
```

Comment: If a variable is binary, then in Stata `summarize, meanonly` returns the proportion of 1s as `r(mean)`.

Comment: Thanks Nick Cox and @Metrics ! I run R code however im not getting the results. I received "Bootstrap Statistics : WARNING: All values of t1* are NA" Here is a sample data summary I want to do bootstrap. The data has missing values. Im not sure if that affects the results.  > describe(q10testfactor)
q10testfactor 
      n missing  unique 
    254     516       2 

0 (58, 23%), 1 (196, 77%)

Comment: This is weird. I increase the R value to R=5000. I got values for std. error but still has NA for the estimates.

Call:
boot(data = x, statistic = myprop, R = 5000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
    original  bias    std. error
t1*       NA      NA  0.01670186

Comment: Of course, you have to first deal with missing data since you are sampling from the data. Did you run with `Stata`?

Comment: Hi Metrics. I tried to vote up the thread but the site wont allow for i dont have enough reputation. I will get back to this thread once I have the required points. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! :-D Didnt know how to do it. but now I know. Thanks!